# Unable to include XHTML in Portlet

Tags: jsf-2, liferay, liferay-6

Hi i am developing a new liferay portlet and richfaces. i the view..xhtml file i need to include another xhtml file. But i end up in invalid location error .

I have included the screen shot and stackrace of the the error. Please tell how to develop and new to liferay development

**view.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<f:view >
    <h:head>
    <ui:include src="/docroot/views/Header.xhtml"/>  
    </h:head>
    <h:body> 
        <h:outputText value="#{i18n['LiferayJSF-hello-world']}" />
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <h:outputText></h:outputText>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /views/view.xhtml @10,49 <ui:include src="/docroot/views/Header.xhtml"> Invalid path : /docroot/views/Header.xhtml
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:164)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:769)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.lifecycle.LifecycleWrapper.render(LifecycleWrapper.java:45)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.execute(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:280)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.execute(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:92)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:99)
    at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doView(GenericFacesPortlet.java:255)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
    at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doDispatch(GenericFacesPortlet.java:204)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:101)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:92)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:638)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:723)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.renderPortlet(PortalImpl.java:3740)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.renderPortlet(PortalUtil.java:1180)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:160)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:94)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:256)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:181)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.includeLayoutContent(LayoutAction.java:370)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:629)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:232)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:153)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:508)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:485)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:309)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.themepreview.ThemePreviewFilter.processFilter(ThemePreviewFilter.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:182)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:254)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:134)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:261)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.themepreview.ThemePreviewFilter.processFilter(ThemePreviewFilter.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:110)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:182)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:222)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:254)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:311)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.threadlocal.ThreadLocalFilter.processFilter(ThreadLocalFilter.java:35)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

[image: Liferay Error]

**Project Structure**

[image]

Comment: Remove /docroot from path, it should resolve your issue.

Comment: Worked how can i add image in xhtml <img src="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/images/thala.jpg" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;height: 280px;"/>

Comment: @PankajKathiriya add as answer for upvote (and a chance to accept). Vivek Shankar, please accept that answer once it's there. You might want to consider asking a separate question with the add-on that you have in your comment: Questions in the comments don't have a good visibility.

Comment: @VivekShankar You have posted **37 questions**, so you should already know how the reputation system works. Your initial question is **answered**, so you should **accept** it and make **new questions** for your new questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `/docroot` from path, it should resolve your issue.

When you give URI as `/resourcenamepath` then it will retrive resource called `resourcename`  from docroot folder of portlet application.

Comment: Pankaj thanks it worked. Do u have idea on inter portlet communication. Please give me some guidance regarding this

Comment: Refer: https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portlet+to+Portlet+Communication